# How to use Vue.compile in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I use `Vue.$compile` to compile function in Vue 3 runtime?
I use the function in Vue 2. For example:

```js
Vue.compile('<custom-component />');
```

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api-treeshaking.html#global-api-treeshaking

Comment: `import  {compile,createApp} from vue; let component = createApp({render:compile('<custom-component />')});`

Comment: @MichalLevý but how I create the vNode which has the attribute $el (like this.$el) and append it to document dynamically

Comment: Well that is e very different question. I suggest you to open new one with the detailed example of your current Vue 2 solution.....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichalLevý  In prosemirror toolkit,I want to compile the vue html code by Vue 3 . I couldn't find an example how to compile html  with vue 3.

Comment: @MichalLevý Thank you for help! I think I will find a solution to parse component with vue 3.

Comment: @minskiter any progress on that? I have the same question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import {compile} from "vue"

compile('<custom-component />')
```

that's all, almost the same!

Then you can do

```
render() {
  return h({render: compile('<custom-component />')})
}
```

As soon as you can't specify imports for the template, if it contains custom components they must have been registered previously with the app.component function at startup: [vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-component](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-component)

Comment: how do you use a custom component? I get the error `Failed to resolve component`

Comment: I did modify my answer, there was a mistake, sorry

Comment: hmm that still didnt work. can you perhaps look at my related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76087375/vue-3-h-with-custom-component/76100028#76100028

Comment: To anyone else finding this, this is how i solved it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76136369/794481

Comment: This does not seem to work wit Vue 3.3, `compile` is always `undefined`

Comment: @Tallboy As soon as you can't specify imports,  if the template contains custom component they must have been registered previously with the app.component function at startup: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-component

Answer (score 0):

Here is the component code I use for that

```
<template>
  <component v-if="component" :is="component" :="$attrs"/>
  <slot v-else></slot>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {compile, type Component, computed} from 'vue'

export interface Props {
  template?: string
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()

const component=computed(() => (props.template?{render : compile(props.template) }:undefined) as Component)

</script>
```

The slot is a fallback if there is no template.
The component is reactive to template change

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `render` and `h` (creates VNode) functions:

```
import { render, h } from 'vue'
import Foo from "../components/Foo.vue"

function makeAFoo(props) {
  const vueComponent = h(Foo, props);
  const el = document.createElement('div')
  render(vueComponent, el)

  document.body.appendChild(el) // append it where you want 
}
```

---

Similar question: [Vue 3 Append Component to the DOM: Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488256/vue-3-append-component-to-the-dom-best-practice)