# Can I load the component template dynamically

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

Is it possible to load the template from server (include components) dynamically? Or can I change the template before it rendered?

I would like to let user to store their own form template into a database and generate the form according to the template-id.

I tried to change the `this.$options.template`, but it seems like only work for vue2.

```js
<!-- static/myproj/js/my-field.vue -->
<template>
<label :for="name+'Fld'" v-html="title"></label>
<input :name="name" :type="text" :value="value" :id="name+'Fld'"/>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props: {
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    value: {type:String, required:false, default:''},
    type:  {type:String, required:true},
    title: {type:String, required:false, default:'Field: '},
  },
  data: function(){ return {}; },
}
</script>
```

```js
// index.vue
const loadVueModuleOpts= {
   moduleCache: {vue: Vue},  
   async getFile(url) {
     const res = await fetch(url);
     if ( !res.ok )
       throw Object.assign(new Error(res.statusText + ' ' + url), { res }); 
     return {
       getContentData: asBinary => asBinary ? res.arrayBuffer() : res.text(),
     }   
   },
};

export default{
   props: {
      id:            {required:true, type:String, default:'abcdefg'},
   }, 

   data: function(){
      this.loadSource();
      return {
         source:     null,
         target:     null,
      };
   },

   template: '<div>I\'m here to be replaced.</div>',

   created: async function(){
      this.$options.template=await axios.get(`/api/template/${id}`).then(resp=>resp.data);
   },

   components: {
      'my-field': Vue.defineAsyncComponent( ()=>loadModule('/static/myproj/js/my-field.vue', loadVueModuleOpts)),
}
```

```html
<!-- server response for /api/template/abcdefg -->
<form action="POST">
   <my-field name="name" title="Your Name: " type="text"/>
   <my-field name="email" title="Email: " type="email"/>
   <input type="submit"/><input type="reset"/>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found [How I can render a component from a string with vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957780/how-i-can-render-a-component-from-a-string-with-vue-3) the example, but when I tried to render, the browser complain about "Failed to resolve component: myfield".

Comment: ```javascript
import{h as t,compile as e}from"vue";export default{props:{id:{required:!0,type:String}},data:function(){return this.loadSource(),{source:null,target:null}},render:function(){return this.target?t(e(this.target)):t("div","Loading Template({{this.id}})...")},methods:{loadSource:function(){axios.get(`/api/tmpls/${this.id}`).then(t=>{this.source=t.data,this.target=t.data.content})}},components:{myfield:Vue.defineAsyncComponent(()=>loadModule("./myfield.vue",loadOpts))}};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. According to [Vue3: How to use Vue.compile in Vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981411/vue3-how-to-use-vue-compile-in-vue3), we can render the template directly by Vue3 like this:

```js
// index.vue
import { h, compile } from 'vue';

const loadVueModuleOpts= {
   moduleCache: {vue: Vue},  
   async getFile(url) {
     const res = await fetch(url);
     if ( !res.ok )
       throw Object.assign(new Error(res.statusText + ' ' + url), { res }); 
     return {
       getContentData: asBinary => asBinary ? res.arrayBuffer() : res.text(),
     }   
   },
};

export default{
   props: {
      id:            {required:true, type:String, default:'abcdefg'},
   }, 

   data: function(){
      this.loadSource();
      return {
         source:     null,
         target:     null,
      };
   },

   // Magic here
   render: function(){
      if(this.target)
         return h(compile(this.target).bind(this));
      return h('div', 'Loading...');
   },

   created: async function(){
      this.$options.template=await axios.get(`/api/template/${id}`).then(resp=>resp.data);
   },

   components: {
      'my-field': Vue.defineAsyncComponent( ()=>loadModule('/static/myproj/js/my-field.vue', loadVueModuleOpts)),
   },
}
```