# Vue js 3 render dynamic component template from server

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a problem with Vue 3, using vue from CDN.
I want to use a template generated by the server, the template is changed but methods and data are not bound.

```html
<script>
// reproduction of the issue in vue3 vite
import { compile, computed, h } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'; // vite
// import { compile, computed, h } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'; // webpack

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      htmlTemplate: '<span @click="test()">this is a test {{ testVariable }}</span>', // This is a test from what would be loaded from the server
      testVariable: 'test variable',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log('test');
    }
  },
  render() {
    const textCompRef = computed(() => ({ render: compile(this.htmlTemplate) }));
    console.log('textCompRef', textCompRef);
    return h(textCompRef.value);
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on **this is a test** then **vue@3:1807 Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function**

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance

I tried setting the template in the create life cycle with this.$options.template = response from the server that worked on 3-rd click and was not changing when new template is loaded.

Comment: Where is `test` and `testVariable` ?

Comment: Test function is in the component methods, test variable is in data of the same component. I will add the missing parts of the code.

Comment: I updated the question to have only the info we need to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this one. Found the answer here:

[Can I load the component template dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75111066/can-i-load-the-component-template-dynamically?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It is the .bind that is the key. In your case it would look like:

```
    render() {
        if (this.htmlTemplate) {                
            return h(compile(this.htmlTemplate, {}).bind(this))
        }
        return h('div', 'Loading...')
    },
```

Comment: Using the exact same code and an error is thrown, because the return value of `compile` is `undefined` ...

Comment: There may be something wrong with the html template in that case.

Comment: I had to include the runtime compiler to make it work: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4158