# Vue 3 h() with custom component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I've read about 100 threads about this and still can't quite get it.

I'm trying to parse a string template from a backend API and render it, using custom components.

I have aliased esm build in `vite.config.js`:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
    },
  },
```

Here is my component:

```
<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent, h } from 'vue';

export default {
  components: {
    PageCalculator: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/PageCalculator.vue')), /* eslint-disable-line */
  },
  props: {
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  render() {
    const render = {
      template: `<div class="content">${this.content}</div>`,
    };
    return h(render);
  },
};
</script>
```

This gives the error `Failed to resolve component`.

how can I go about dynamically loading the component? I have a large number of components that the backend can send back, so I wanted to lazily load them.

Here is how it's used from the outer component:

```
<app-page :title="page.title" container-class="w-full">
  <compiled-content :content="page.content_html" />
</app-page>
```

The content of the HTML might look like this (the `content` prop):

```
<p>this is a nice sentence</p>
<page-calculator />
<p>this is a <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">link</router-link></p>
```

Comment: where are you using `PageCalculator`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim i edited my question. its HTML coming in as a prop

Comment: Have you tried defining the src alias with [path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path)? `alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src') }`. I haven't seen a configuration like yours before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, this was such a painful journey, yet the answer is so simple.

**here is how you render vue components from the server dynamically, even if they're mixed within html**

I'm extremely surprised the answer is not in more places... people had me registering global components, using methods that didnt't work. I actually eventually just stumbled across it on my own while trying to piece together tons of different answers.

Here's the final version that:

1. compiles vue code in realtime from the server
2. does so with components and methods IN that component, without requiring global components

```
<script>
import { h } from 'vue';
import AppAlert from '@/components/AppAlert.vue';

export default {
  props: {
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  render() {
    const r = {
      components: {
        AppAlert,
      },
      template: `<div class="content">${this.content || ''}</div>`,
      methods: {
        hello() {
          // method "hello" is also available here
        },
      },
    };
    return h(r);
  },
};
</script>
```

If you have tons of components in your content you can also make them all async components:

```
components: {
  AppAlert: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/AppAlert.vue')), 
  ...
```

Comment: wow this is... so simple and so much better. Thank you SO much for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

You should better use Vue [`slots`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) for content instead of `props`

And you should also not interpolate HTML, since it will not work with components.

```
template: `<div class="content">${this.content}</div>`,
```

Use Vue [`Render Functions`](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) instead.

```js
const { createApp, h, defineAsyncComponent  } = Vue;

const test = { template: 'Test' }
const PageCalculator = 
  defineAsyncComponent(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                
       resolve( { template: 'My PageCalculator' } )
    })
  })

const CompiledContent = {
  template: 'Slot: <slot></slot>'  
}

const App = { 
  components:  {CompiledContent, PageCalculator }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
 <compiled-content><page-calculator></page-calculator></compiled-content>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. How would this work with my full example with the actual text? These will be 2000+ word pages with vue components mixed in.

Comment: It does not matter what do you put inside the slot. Just build your code around the concept or adopt it on your code base.